# On Linux, how to tell how many cores of the machine are active?

Tags: linux, core

On Linux, how to tell how many cores of the machine are active? I assume a test for this would work for Android too.
I need to know if more than one core is ever active. Was wondering to test this by having a process create many threads. Is it possible for a thread to query which processor it is on? that way one can tell if multiple cores will ever be used under heavy load. Not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: By "active", I assume you mean how many cores are currently in use?  Or do you mean how many cores the system has?

Comment: yes, I would like to tell how many are currently in use

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `top` to list the utilization of each core.  Press 1 if necessary to split the CPU row into a separate row for each core.

You can also add a column that shows the last-used core for each process.  Press f to bring up the field list, then j to activate the "P" column.  Then press space to return to the live view.

Comment: So perhaps I should write and run a program that spawns many threads and then run the 'top' command in the console?

Comment: I think that should work.  Just press H when you're in `top` to list threads separately.  Or you could write a program with an infinite loop and run it a bunch of times.

Comment: Say, I write the program to spawn 100 threads, each one performing some long, intensive computation. If I write it in Java (Android), is there a guarantee that the JVM/KVM will run the threads on different cores, and run them on all the cores?

Comment: I don't know - isn't that what your experiment is supposed to figure out?

Comment: I need to test a program that says it will restrict the number of processor cores being used. I shall search some more. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`ps` has a field called `psr` to tell you which processor a job is running on.

So you could use something like:

```
ps -e -o psr= | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

---

Note that merely running `ps` like this will of course make at least one core active.

Probably better is to run this:

```
tmp=/tmp/ps.$$
ps -e -o psr= > /tmp/ps.$$
sort -u "$tmp" | wc -l
rm "$tmp"
```

that way the `sort` and `wc` do not increase the count.

Comment: What if system has 16 cores and nobody is using some of them?

Comment: Then it prints 0 because none of them are in use.  I think that is what the question is asking for.

Comment: Didn't see new comments to the question.

Comment: Of course, by running `ps` we are making at least 1 core active. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The disadvantage is I need to know if more than one core is ever active. Was wondering to test this by having a process create many threads. Is it possible for a **thread** to query which processor it is on? that way one can tell if multiple cores will ever be used under heavy load. Not sure if I am on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Here's a [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/09/read-android-cpu-info.html) to an Android Java example.

Comment: By "active", I assume Anil means how many cores are currently in use, and how many are idle, i.e. an approximation of how busy the system is.  `/proc/cpuinfo` just tells you how many cores the system has, and even you would have to do more than `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to account for HyperThreading.

Comment: OK - that wasn't clear but you're right.

Answer (score 2):

```
htop
```

This command works good in both ubuntu and centos and shows graphically how many CPUs and how are they being used.

for centos:

```
yum install htop
```

for ubuntu:

```
apt-get install htop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible`
or
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online`

Possible is mainly in case you have isolated a CPU to run some particular program.